# Correct way to have a one time login iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to create an app that will require a login upon first time load. Once the user logged in successfully the credentials will be stored in a keychain so the user doesn't have to keep logging in.

Here is a quick mockup of the following code I've written; Is using the `AppDelegate` the correct way to go about handling which View to show first?

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "KeychainItemWrapper.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TestBViewController.h"
#import "User.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) TestBViewController *mainVC;  //  User see's after loggin in
@property (strong, nonatomic) User *user;
@property (strong, nonatomic) KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem;

- (void)saveKeychainUsername:(NSString *)username andPassword:(NSString *)password;
- (void)loadLoggedInViewControllers;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"AppUniqueID" accessGroup:nil];

//    [self.keychainItem resetKeychainItem];

UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

// Override point for customization after application launch.

NSString *password = [self.keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
NSString *username = [self.keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];

NSLog(@"username: %@, password: %@", username, password);

if ([username length] <= 0 || [password length] <= 0) {
    // Login VC
    ViewController *loginVC = (ViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];
    self.window.rootViewController = loginVC;
} else {
    [self loadLoggedInViewControllers];
}

return YES;
}

- (void)loadLoggedInViewControllers {
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

//  Attempt to login user
self.user = [[User alloc] init];

self.user.name = @"Bob";
self.user.hasAccess = YES;
//  If user is no longer valid (for whatever reason) remove his keychain information so we can save the new ones.

//  Valid user! Skip Login VC
self.mainVC = (TestBViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main"];
self.mainVC.user = self.user;

self.window.rootViewController = self.mainVC;
}
```

**ViewController.m** - Think of this as my LoginViewController

```
- (IBAction)storePassButtonTap:(id)sender {

if ([[username text] length] > 0 && [[password text] length] > 0) {
     AppDelegate *shareDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [shareDelegate saveKeychainUsername:[username text] andPassword:[password text]];

    [shareDelegate loadLoggedInViewControllers];
} else {
    if ([[username text] length] <= 0) {
        //  Error message
    }

    if ([[password text] length] <= 0) {
        //  Error message
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I was going to originally, but Stackoverflow doesn't generally like when you ask these type of questions either.

Comment: +1, I dont understand the downvote for this. Asking best approach is normally off-topic for stackoverflow and my understanding is that these questions should be asked here.

Comment: @ACB - subjective questions are still subjective questions regardless of where they are asked.

Comment: @ChrisF, I think this is a question about design patterns and algorithm which is supposed to be on-topic here. If this is subjective, don't you think this question is subjective: [What should every programmer know about web development?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development). But still that is the highest voted question here.

Comment: @ACB - I wasn't saying that this question was necessarily off topic, but "best approach" is always a red flag for a subjective question.

Answer (score 2):

I wont recommend doing this. I have done this in the past and I have faced problems such as the orientation delegates were not working once I change the rootviewcontroller property of appdelegate like this. Looks like it is fixed in iOS 6, but my understanding is that this is something unusual and not supposed to do.

Instead have a dummy viewcontroller as rootviewcontroller and add other viewcontrollers as its childViewController. You can remove and add any view controller this way.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I wouldn't. I use storyboards and would set a view controller as the root. If I need to do this I would leave the view controller blank (maybe have an activity indicator if it takes a minute to login), run the login code here and then either move to the login segue or the main app segue.

Making sure that both the next screens hide the back button so the user can't go back to this screen.

I like the leave the appDeleage for things like reestablishing tcp connections and closing them when entering background.